# Your Query does not include the specified expression, how to fix it?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't understand why my sql is not running, 
it pop out a window say

> "Your query does not include the specified expression `' SUM(SaleRecord.Number)*(product.Price'` as part of an aggregate function"

```
SELECT SUM(SaleRecord.Number)*(Product.Price) AS TotalIncome
FROM Product, SaleRecord
WHERE Product.ProductID=SaleRecord.SaleProduct;
```

Comment: You will need a `GROUP BY Product.Price` to be able to use the `SUM()` aggregate properly while multiplying by price.  But that still may not be the result you are after. Please post a small sample of each table, together with a sample of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: thank you very much for helping, but this sort of get my confuse, because the output that I need is the total income of the shop. (my database is about a shop) So that should be only a number there, So I don't really understand what group by will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked in my previous answer:

> "thank you, I just make some mistake, now it is working. And sorry to
>   bother you more, I want to select the product who sell the most out,
>   how can I do it, I try to add MAX(xxx) on it, and it don't work"

Now, I am by no means an expert, but there are two processes going on. Your language is confusing so I'm going to assume you want to know which product sells the most in $$ terms (rather than count. For example, you might sell 1,000 $0.50 products, equallying $500 total sales, or 10 $500 products, totallying $5000. If you want the count or the dollar value, then the method changes slightly).

So the first process is to get the total sales of each product, which I outlined above. Then you want to nest that inside a second query, where you then select the max. I'll give you the code and then explain it:

```
SELECT ProductID, MAX(TotalSale)
FROM (
      SELECT P.ProductID, SUM(S.Number)*P.Price AS TotalSale
      FROM Products as P, SaleRecords as S
      WHERE product.Productid = SaleRecord.SaleProduct
      GROUP BY Product.ProductID
      )
```

It's easiest to imagine this as querying a query. Your first query is in the FROM() statement. That will run and give you the output of total sale per product. Then the second query is ran (the top most SELECT line) that selects the productID and the sale amount that is the largest among all the products.

Your teacher may not like this since nesting queries is a little advanced (though completely intuitive IMO). Hopefully this helps!

Comment: So many thanks to you, don't worry about teacher, like he won't expect a beginner level student can write pretty SQL XD. It seems work fine, only problem is it pop up a window ask me enter Parameter value.

Comment: Typically when the dialogue to enter a parameter pops up, it's because there's a problem in your specification. You might be able to solve it by giving an alias to the subquery. So after the last parenthesis add ` as sub` and then fully specify the second queries column titles (ie: sub.ProductID, MAX(sub.TotalSale))

Answer (score 2):

`Product.Price` is not part of the aggregate.  Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT SUM(SaleRecord.Number * Product.Price) AS TotalIncome
FROM Product INNER JOIN
     SaleRecord
     ON Product.ProductID=SaleRecord.SaleProduct;
```

Note that I also fixed the archaic `join` syntax.

Comment: thanks you very much for answering, I didn't use inner join cause teacher didn't talk about it much as me a beginner level student. It will be looks like that is not my own work.

Comment: You should never use commas in the `from` clause.  It is a shame your teacher is teaching you bad style.

Comment: guess because my course is a business course, not a IT relate course, so teacher don't really expect us to be that good..

Answer (score 0):

You brackets are wrong - for each row you want to multiply the `price` by the `number`, and only then `sum` them:

```
SELECT SUM(SaleRecord.Number * Product.Price) AS TotalIncome
FROM   Product, SaleRecord
WHERE  Product.ProductID = SaleRecord.SaleProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bracket error:

```
SELECT SUM(SaleRecord.Number * Product.Price) AS TotalIncome
FROM Product INNER JOIN
    SaleRecord ON Product.ProductID = SaleRecord.SaleProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not indicating which column to group by. The line you wrote is:

`SUM(SaleRecord.Number) * Product.Price`

Which sums all of the sale quantities (regardless of differences in product ID) and multiplies it by the price right? Well what if you have multiple products with different prices? Basically, you are doing a one to many match, where you have a total that is the sum of all the sales, multiplied by multiple prices. What you need is a group by command. I would modify your code to say:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, SUM(SaleRecord.Number)*Product.Price AS TotalSales
FROM Product, SaleRecord
WHERE product.Productid = SaleRecord.SaleProduct
GROUP BY Product.ProductID
```

That should take care of it, telling the dbms to group each product together, sum the number of sales and then multiply by the price of that product.

You can nest that inside another query to get total Income:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalIncome)
FROM ( **the above code here)
```

EDIT: Or you can do it like the ways listed above where your query creates a TotalIncome for each *ORDER*, and then sums them all together. my way creates a total sale for each *PRODUCT* and then sums all the products

Comment: thank you very much for helping, but this sort of get my confuse, because the output that I need is the total income of the shop. (my database is about a shop) So that should be only a number there, So I don't really understand what group by will do.

Comment: @DawnKitty then your best bet is to follow the above statements, but if you were interested in what products contributed to your total income, then my way would be prefered because it groups your sales by product. Your return will just be a list of the products and the total sales amount for each product. That way if you had 20 products, you could easily convert it into a pie chart showing the percentage of total income that each product contributed during your time period. Or you could just as easily sum all the sales into a "total income" :)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, That SQL on top is working on total income. And I have another query that really work on total income of each item.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is it giving you an error or returning the wrong results?

Comment: thank you, I just make some mistake, now it is working. And sorry to bother you more, I want to select the product who sell the most out, how can I do it, I try to add MAX(xxx) on it, and it don't work..

Comment: See my second answer (forthcoming)